# Creating an Array Object student and adding it to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Can you help me regarding my problem with my array of objects class person? Everytime I run the program I'm having a null pointer problem. Here's the code.

```
List<Student> listPerson = new ArrayList<>();
Student[] stud = null;
int counter = 0;

ResultSet rs = DBMSConnection.GetDetails();

while(rs.next()){

    stud[counter] = new Student();
    stud[counter].setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
    stud[counter].setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));
    stud[counter].setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
    counter++;    
}

for( int i = 0 ; i < counter ; i++){
    listPerson.add(stud[i]);
}
```

**This is the edit that you added to other answers**

What I really want is like this guys.

```
 Student stud = new Student();
 stud.firstname = "john";
 stud.lastname = "doe";


 Student stud2 = new Student();
 stud2.firstname = "Mike";
 stud2.lastname = "doe";

 List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(stud);
 list.add(stud2);
```

Note: Is there a way I can instantiate Student stud inside a loop; eg.

```
int record = 100;
Student[] sa = null;

for(int i = 0; i<record; i++){
  sa[i] = new Student[]; //instantiate Objects on the fly
  list.add(sa[i]);
}
```

I want to assign all the first record into the first object instance, like stud has the values of the first record stud2 has the second record and pass it to the list.

Comment: By the way, what I'm trying to do here is I'm accessing the database and looping to all student records one after another and passing it to the program by using the resultset. In my mind I'm creating a dynamic array of objects class student and getting the details from the database. Need some guide here. Thanks

Comment: ¿What is the size of your array "Student[] stud = null"?  It never changes from null, so the size is 0...and you are adding new elements to the array. You do not really need that array. Just this: "while(rs.next()){ listPerson.add(new Student(rs.getString("first_name"),rs.getString("last_name"),rs.getString("address"));" Note: you need to create a non empty constructor with all the student details.

Comment: The Student[] class object array should be dynamic, because I dont want to keep track of the size of the array I just wanna create a dynamic array just to hold a large values of array. Technically the size of the Student object should match with the size of the records.

Comment: As per the **edit** in your question.  See my answer it is achieving exactly what you want.  You do not need to have `Student` in an array.  You do not need to have different variables names for your `Student` **BECAUSE** every time that your loop iterates it re-declares the `Student` object and the code re-initialises the values that will be stored in the `Student` Object.  Just follow my code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your array is null `Student[] stud = null;` as it never changes from null BUT in reality you do not need an array

consider

```
   ResultSet rs = DBMSConnection.GetDetails();

    while(rs.next()){

        Student stud = new Student();
        stud.setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
        stud.setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));
        stud.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
        listPerson.add(stud);
   }
```

**edit**

You can later iterate through this ArrayList as follows

```
for (Student student: listPerson) {
    System.out.println (student.getFirst()); 
}
```

Comment: Ic, but the problem is I have a multiple values in my database and I want to create an array of Students and adding it to Student objects. Will it work?? I'm trying to create a multiple instance of Student class and such as stud, stud1, stud2 dynamically

Comment: I want to get all the values and pass it to my JTable, I'm not using the rs2xml libraries.. just wanna code the data manually. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Yes, for each record that you retrieve from your DB, you are adding a new Student to the ArrayList.

Comment: Have a look at the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: It will work when I modified the code but the problem is I'm just getting the last record. I think my problem is the array of object student. Is there a way I can create an array of objects with dynamic index and pass it to a loop

Comment: see my edit to my answer.  If this does explain enough for you, please edit your question with code that you are trying to use

Comment: As you can see in my code, the Student is added inside of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects in Java that store multiple variables of the same type. Arrays
can hold either primitives or object references, but the array itself will always be an object on the heap, even if the array is declared to hold primitive elements.

Constructing an array means creating the array object on the heap (where all
objects live)—that is, doing a new on the array type. To create an array object, Java must know how much space to allocate on the heap, so you must specify the size of the array at creation time. The size of the array is the number of elements the array will hold.

If you want manage your data dynamically, you can use one of the Collection types from java.util (including HashMap, ArrayList, TreeSet).

In your case,

```
List<Student> listPerson = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = DBMSConnection.GetDetails();

while(rs.next()){

    Student stud = new Student();
    stud.setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
    stud.setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));
    stud.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
    listPerson.add(stud);
}
```

After while loop over this job, you get all your data (`listPerson`) and can pass to your JTable for parsing or etc.

Comment: It will work guys but sad to say is that I can only get the last record. What I'm trying to do is to get all the values from the database using hard coded java codes. I don't want to use some libraries for now such as rs2xml, because I'm planning to take some Gov't exams for Java in my country. I appreciate your comments but I still didn't find the solutions.

Comment: What I really need is I want to instantiate the object Student dynamically. Is there anyway I can Instantiate the person class inside a loop dnynamically e.g. Stud[0],Stud[1],Stud[2] inside a function and assign each values into it and pass it to a listPerson.

Comment: @kornben This is exactly what my answer is doing.  I think that you have some fundamental misunderstanding and your question is not clearly saying what is going wrong.  Please consider to update your question with more information and/or code so that we can help